# Can transparent activity write in Sd card

Tags: android

I have an activity which was able to write data in sd card on click of a button on it. I made the activity transparent and removed the onclick code from oncreate method. Now when I call the activity, it is unable to write in sd card. Can there be any reason why it is happening?

Comment: why can't you prefer to have service to complete this task?

Comment: Well I am trying all possible combinations, research work

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured something out, calling 
`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

after the code for writing in sd card does the trick. Calling these two in the beginning was causing the problem.